# Change default screen resolution on headless ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, headless, xvfb

I am running a jenkins instance on a headless ubuntu server. For some of the GUI tests, I get the following error

```
org.assertj.swing.exception.ActionFailedException: The component to click is out of the boundaries of the screen
```

How can I set my screen resolution?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xvfb this might be what you are looking for:

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args "-screen 0 1024x768x24" ant test
```

This will adjust the virtual screen size. Replace "ant test" with your own command.